# How to change graph interpolation type in headless mode

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes

I'm writing a script for Blender that needs to be run from the terminal. I would like to change the interpolation type of f-curves in my script. When using Blender's normal UI, the sequence of commands for what I want to accomplish is:

```
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'FCURVES'
bpy.ops.graph.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.graph.interpolation_type(type='BACK')
```

This works great when I run the code within Blender, however when I try to execute this from the terminal, I receive the following error:

```
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'FCURVES'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ui_type'
```

This is understandable, because in headless mode, apparently there is no area or UI. How can I achieve the same results in headless mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No UI in headless mode.**

There are a number of similar questions.

[Change extrapolation type from Python running in the background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65476/change-extrapolation-type-from-python-running-in-the-background?rq=1)

Look for lower level API calls.  In the UI the interpolation is set from the *`Keys`* Menu indicating that it is a property of an fcurve's  keyframe point.

```
>>> action = D.actions['CubeAction']
>>> fcurve = action.fcurves[0]
>>> fcurve.keyframe_points[0].interpolation
'BEZIER'

>>> fcurve.keyframe_points[0].interpolation = 'BACK'
>>>
```

Consult the docs on [`bpy.types.Keyframe`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html?highlight=bpy%20types%20keyframe#bpy.types.Keyframe.interpolation) for options, or to get valid enums from error message feedback

```
>>> fcurve.keyframe_points[0].interpolation = 'FOO'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "FOO" not found in ('CONSTANT', 'LINEAR', 'BEZIER', 'SINE', 'QUAD', 'CUBIC', 'QUART', 'QUINT', 'EXPO', 'CIRC', 'BACK', 'BOUNCE', 'ELASTIC')
```